# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'db.models.Inventory.InventoryModel' is not mapped

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am in the process of building several example APIs to and ran into this 'is not mapped' sqlalchemy.orm.exe.UnmappedInstance Error issue. I believe this error would possible be generated if I was trying to pass an object instance that wasn't a model, however, I am passing a pydanic model within the db.add() method which is mapped (or at least I think it is.) So, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when the object being passed to db.Add (new_inventory) is a prudence model that is aligned to the base schema. What am I missing? Or educate me on why I'm getting a Unmapped Instance Error when I can clearly see that the type received is a mapped pedantic model.  I've raved existing Stack Overflow post which was centered around using marshmallows, which I prefer to make that an 'if all else fails' solution. Any solution to get the code I have in place massaged would be highly appreciated.
Using Python 3.10.4 / Pydantic / SqlAlchemy / FastAPI

## file name c:\app\main.py

```
from msilib import schema
mport psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor  
from os import stat
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Response, status,     HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
import pdb
from db.conn import Postgre
from db.sql_alchemy import db_engine, fetch_db, Base
from db.models.Inventory import InventorySchema, InventoryModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from pydantic import BaseModel

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=db_engine)

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/fetch/vehicles", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    def fetch_vehiles(db: Session = Depends(fetch_db)):        
        vehicles = db.query(InventorySchema).all() 
        print(vehicles)
        return {"all vehicles": vehicles}

    
 @app.post("/post/vehicles",status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        def insert_vechiles(inventory: InventoryModel, db: Session = Depends(fetch_db)):    
    
            new_inventory = InventoryModel(
                        name = inventory.name,
                        price = inventory.price,
                        color = inventory.color,
                        manufactured_by = inventory.manufactured_by,
                        model = inventory.model,
                        size = inventory.size,
                        quantity = inventory.quantity,
                        active = inventory.active)
            pdb.set_trace()
            db.add(new_inventory)  # <---generates error 
            # db.commit()
            # db.refresh(new_intentory)
            return {"Posted": new_inventory}

    # file name: c:\db\models\Inventory.py
    from email.policy import default
    from msilib import schema
    from xmlrpc.client import Boolean, boolean
    from psycopg2 import Timestamp

    from pydantic import BaseModel
    from db.sql_alchemy import Base
    from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP, Column, Integer, String, Boolean
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
    from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import TIMESTAMP


    class InventoryModel(BaseModel):    
        name: str = 'Yshmael'
        price: str = '3.00'
        color: str  = 'blue'
        manufactured_by: str = 'ford'
        model: str = 'branch'
        size: str = '4 door'
        quantity: str = '10'
        active: str = 'False'


    class InventorySchema(Base):
        __tablename__ = "vehicles"

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
        name  = Column(String, nullable=False)
        price = Column(String, nullable=False)
        color = Column(String, nullable=False)
        manufactured_by = Column(String, nullable=False)
        model = Column(String, nullable=False)
        size = Column(String, nullable=False)
        quantity = Column(String, nullable=False)
        active = Column(String, nullable=False)
        created_on = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, 
     server_default=text('now()'))
```

StackTrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 366, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 269, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 93, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 670, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 266, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 227, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 162, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\.\app\main.py", line 40, in insert_vechiles
    db.add(new_inventory)
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2605, in add
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\QA\Dev\projects\testdriven.io\posting_system\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
**sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'db.models.Inventory.InventoryModel' is not mapped**
```

Comment: Please don't use images on stack overflow, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confused with the inheritance of model and schema, **BaseModel is for schemas and Base is for models**.

Try to change the classes of:

```
class InventoryModel(BaseModel):    

class InventorySchema(Base):
        __tablename__ = "vehicles"
```

to:

```
class InventoryModel(Base):
        __tablename__ = "vehicles"

class InventorySchema(BaseModel):
```